# Problem with System.Data with Sybase SQL Anywhere and Windows CE

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce, sqlanywhere

I am moving a vb.net application from Oracle Lite to Sybase SQL anywhere.  I have made several code changes but have a specific error that is driving me mad.  All of this is in Visual Studio 2005.

When I compile the code it gives me the following error "Reference required to assembly 'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' containing the base class 'System.Data.Common.DbCommand'. Add one to your project".

I have both System and System.Data added for the WindowsCE platform and these worked fine under the Oracle Lite system.  I have removed and re-added these files to the project.  Nothing seems to be working to get rid of the error.

The offending code is legion, one example is:

```
Public con As ULConnection
```

Any thoughts here would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A public Key Token of `b77a5c561934e089` indicates a full framework, not compact framework, assembly.  Something you're using (likely the version of SQL Anywhere you have) was built referencing the desktop System.Data assembly, which is not going to work on a device.  You need assemblies built specifically targeting the Compact Framework.